# Algorithm that generates orthogonal vectors: C++ implementation

Tags: c++, beginner, vectors

Recently I asked the [similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229244/algorithm-that-spans-orthogonal-vectors-python), but the algorithm was implemented in Python. Now I've tried to implement the same algorithm, but in C++ (I'm *very* new to it):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<cmath>
#include <tgmath.h>
using namespace std;



const int MAXRANGE = 1000;

int randint(int low, int high){
    return rand() % (high - low) + low;

    }

void generate_vector(float vec[],int dimension){
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        vec[i] = randint(-MAXRANGE,MAXRANGE);
        }

    // We need to ensure that the last entry doesn't equal to zero

    if (vec[dimension-1] == 0){
        while (vec[dimension-1] == 0){
            vec[dimension-1] = randint(-MAXRANGE,MAXRANGE);

        }
    }


}

void generate_orthogonal (float *vector, float orthogonal_vector[], int dimension){
    float last_entry;
    float dot_product = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension -1; i++){
        orthogonal_vector[i] = randint(-MAXRANGE,MAXRANGE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension -1; i++){
        dot_product = dot_product + (vector[i] * orthogonal_vector[i]);
    }
    last_entry = -(dot_product/vector[dimension-1]);
    orthogonal_vector[dimension-1] = last_entry;
}


float dot_product(float *vector1, float vector2[],int dimension){
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        sum += (vector1[i])*(vector2[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}


void print_vector(float *A,int dim){
    cout << "(";
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        if (i == dim -1){
            cout << A[i];
        }
        else{
            cout << A[i] << ",";}
    }
    cout << ")^T" << endl;
}
int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    int dimension;
    cout << "Choose dimension for the vector: ";
    cin >> dimension;
    float arbitrary_vector[dimension], orthogonal[dimension];
    generate_vector(arbitrary_vector,dimension);
    generate_orthogonal(arbitrary_vector,orthogonal,dimension);
    cout << "First vector: ";
    print_vector(arbitrary_vector,dimension);
    cout << "Orthogonal vector: ";
    print_vector(orthogonal,dimension);
    cout << "Dot product of the vectors: ";
    cout << dot_product(arbitrary_vector,orthogonal,dimension) << endl;

}
```

---

What can be improved?

---

As some people previously pointed out, the algorithm would throw exception if the last entry of the first vector was \$0\$. I made an a slight change to ensure that `generate_vector` function won't generate vector where the last element is zero.

Comment: Hi Nelver!  Since you are very new to C++, I have added the beginner tag for you.  As a beginner, this helps you get reviews that stick a bit closer to the basics and explain a bit more about the how and why.  See [Why is the \[beginner\] tag appropriate here as opposed to e.g. Stack Overflow?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9327).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to C++!  This code review focuses on writing idiomatic C++ code.

> ```
> #include<iostream>
> #include<cstdlib>
> #include<ctime>
> #include<cmath>
> #include <tgmath.h>
> ```

Don't `#include <tgmath.h>` because it is deprecated.  It just includes `#include <complex>` and `#include <cmath>`.  In this case, you do not use complex numbers, and you have `#include <cmath>`.

It is common practice to place a space after `#include` to improve readability.  Also, sorting the `#include` directives makes them easier to navigate:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
```

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Well, no.  `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice in C++ because it potentially introduces name clashes.  See [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721).

Instead, explicitly qualify the names with `std::`.  This won't be a lot of effort once you get used to it, but it really helps to avoid subtle problems.

> ```
> const int MAXRANGE = 1000;
> ```

Constants are indicated with `constexpr` in C++.  In general, `constexpr` allows the constant to be used in more loci than `const` does.

ALL CAPS names are usually reserved for macros.  They are not commonly used for constants.

> ```
> int randint(int low, int high){
>     return rand() % (high - low) + low;
>
>     }
> ```

The indentation is a bit irregular.  There is usually a line break or space before the `{`.

`rand` is infamous for being a low-quality random number generator.  Use `<random>` instead.  See [Why is the new random library better than `std::rand()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53040940).  Time is also not always considered a good seed.  `std::random_device` is better.  The function can be rewritten like this:

```
int randint(int low, int high)
{
    static std::mt19937 engine{std::random_device{}()};

    assert(low <= high);    
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{low, high};
    return dist(engine);
}
```

Note that I used `assert` (defined in header `<cassert>`) to express the pre-condition.

> ```
> void generate_vector(float vec[],int dimension){
>     for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
>         vec[i] = randint(-MAXRANGE,MAXRANGE);
>         }
>
>     // We need to ensure that the last entry doesn't equal to zero
>
>     if (vec[dimension-1] == 0){
>         while (vec[dimension-1] == 0){
>             vec[dimension-1] = randint(-MAXRANGE,MAXRANGE);
>
>         }
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```

Several problems:

- Containers from the standard library are generally preferred over raw C arrays.  Use `std::vector` instead.
- You should really be generating `float` values instead of `int` values.
- Using out-parameters is less idiomatic than using the return value.
- Retrying is not a good strategy to ensure that the last entry is non-zero.  Generating a number in `[-maxrange, 0)` and then having a 50% chance of negating the sign is probably better.
- You can use standard algorithms (available in header `<algorithm>`) to simplify the code.

Here's how I would fix these problems (without using `randint`).  I have added some comments to help you understand.

```
constexpr float maxrange = 1000.0f;

std::mt19937 engine{std::random_device{}()};

std::vector<float> generate_vector(int dimension)
{
    assert(dimension > 0);

    // generate the first (n - 1) elements
    std::vector<float> result(dimension);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist{-maxrange, maxrange};
    std::generate(result.begin(), result.end() - 1, []{ return dist(engine); });

    // generate the last element
    dist.param({-maxrange, 0});
    result.back() = dist(engine);
    // negate the sign with a 50% possibility
    if (std::bernoulli_distribution bdist{0.5}; bdist(engine))
        result.back() = -result.back();

    // NRVO, no copying, no performance degradation
    return result;
}
```

Also, `double` is generally used instead of `float` in C++ unless you have a good reason.

---

> ```
> void generate_orthogonal (float *vector, float orthogonal_vector[], int dimension){
>     float last_entry;
>     float dot_product = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i < dimension -1; i++){
>         orthogonal_vector[i] = randint(-MAXRANGE,MAXRANGE);
>     }
>     for (int i = 0; i < dimension -1; i++){
>         dot_product = dot_product + (vector[i] * orthogonal_vector[i]);
>     }
>     last_entry = -(dot_product/vector[dimension-1]);
>     orthogonal_vector[dimension-1] = last_entry;
> }
> ```

Some problems, in addition to the aforementioned ones:

- Use `++i`, not `i++`, in the `for` statement.  See [Difference between pre-increment and post-increment in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/484462).
- You have the dot product function later, you can use it.
- The elements of `vector` should be `const`.
- The `last_entry` variable is not necessary; just assign the result of the calculation directly to `orthogonal_vector[dimension - 1]`.  It should be obvious that we are referring to the last entry if `.back()` is used.

Note that dot product is available in the standard library as `std::inner_product` (available in header `<numeric>`), so no need to roll out your own.

```
std::vector<float> generate_orthogonal(const std::vector<float>& vector)
{
    // at least one dimension
    assert(!vector.empty());

    // same
    std::vector<float> result(dimension);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist{-maxrange, maxrange};
    std::generate(result.begin(), result.end() - 1, []{ return dist(engine); });

    // generate the last element
    auto dot_product = std::inner_product(vector.begin(), vector.end() - 1, result.begin());
    result.back() = -dot_product / vector.back();

    // same
    return result;
}
```

> ```
> float dot_product(float *vector1, float vector2[],int dimension){
>     float sum = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
>         sum += (vector1[i])*(vector2[i]);
>     }
>     return sum;
> }
> ```

As I said before, this function is available in the standard library as `std::inner_product`.

> ```
> void print_vector(float *A,int dim){
>     cout << "(";
>     for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
>         if (i == dim -1){
>             cout << A[i];
>         }
>         else{
>             cout << A[i] << ",";}
>     }
>     cout << ")^T" << endl;
> }
> ```

[Don't use `std::endl` without a reason.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907)  Use `\n` instead.

You can simplify the code by printing the first element first:

```
void print_vector(const std::vector<float>& vector)
{
    assert(!vector.empty());

    std::cout << '(' << vector[0];
    for (auto it = vector.begin() + 1; it != vector.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << ", " << *it;
    }
    std::cout << ")^T\n";
}
```

---

You may noticed that `assert(!vector.empty())` appeared several times in the code.  Maybe write a class for that.

Comment: Nice review, there is always benefit in a second set of eyes. Especially if it is a throrough as yours

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning `std::random_device` for seeding. I have some old code to update.

Comment: The prefix/postfix page you link says specifically it does not matter which is used in the kinds of `for` loops in the OP.

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to C++.

It seems that you are more or less trying to write C code rather than C++ though. Lets have a look at what you can improve:

1. Never do `using namespace std;` It is a terrible practise that gets you into trouble really fast. `std::` is not that hard to type so get in the habit early.
2. If you have compile time constants use them via `constexpr`
3. Your `dot_product` function is already implemented in the standard library. It is called `inner_product`. So the following code can be replaced

   > ```
   > float dot_product(float *vector1, float vector2[],int dimension){
   >     float sum = 0;
   >     for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
   >         sum += (vector1[i])*(vector2[i]);
   >     }
   >     return sum;
   > }
   > ```

   by the following code

   ```
   std::inner_product(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), b.cbegin(), float(0.0));
   ```
4. Similarly there is a `generate` function that fills a vector with a generator. Note that C++ has a variety of good random number generators (`rand()` is not one of them) in the `<random>` header. I don't know why you use integers for the float vectors but you can adapt that easily.

   EDIT: Incorporated problems found by @L.F.

   ```
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <random>

   class randomStreamUniformInt {
   public:
       explicit randomStreamUniformInt(int lower_bound, int upper_bound)
       : mt(std::random_device{}()), uniform_dist(lower_bound, upper_bound) {}
       explicit randomStreamUniformInt(int lower_bound, int upper_bound, double seed)
       : mt(seed), uniform_dist(lower_bound, upper_bound) {}

       int operator() () { return uniform_dist(mt); }
   private:
       std::mt19937_64                     mt;
       std::uniform_int_distribution<>     uniform_dist;
   };

   static randomStreamUniformInt rng(-MAXRANGE, MAXRANGE); 

   std::vector<float> generate random(const std::size_t numElements) {
       std::vector<float> res(numElements);
       std::generate(res.begin(), res.end(), rng);
       return res;
   }
   ```

   It would be even better to pass the random number generator as an argument rather than a global variable. I leave that as an exercise.
5. You should use standard facilities for arrays such as `std::vector` or `std::array` depending on whether you know the size at compile time. So the following code:

   > ```
   > float arbitrary_vector[dimension], orthogonal[dimension]
   > ```

   Should be better written as

   ```
   std::vector<float> arbitrary_vector = generate_random(dimension);
   ```

   Note that it is always better to put each declaration into a single line.
6. Your method `generate_orthogonal` can be improved accordingly.

   ```
   std::vector<float> generate_orthogonal(const std::vector<float>& a) {
       // get some random data
       std::vector<float> b = generate_random(a.size());

       // find the last non zero entry in a
       // We have to turn the reverse iterator into an iterator via std::prev(rit.base())
       auto IsZero = [] (const float f) -> bool { return f == float(0.0);};
       auto end = std::prev(std::find_if_not(a.crbegin(), a.crend(), IsZero).base());

       // determine the dot product up to end
       float dot_product = std::inner_product(a.cbegin(), end, b.cbegin(), float(0.0));

       // set the value of b so that the inner product is zero
       b[std::distance(a.cbegin(), end)] = - dot_product / (*end);

       return b;
   }
   ```

So put together it would look something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

constexpr int MAXRANGE = 1000;

class randomStreamUniformInt {
public:
    explicit randomStreamUniformInt(int lower_bound, int upper_bound)
    : mt(std::random_device{}()), uniform_dist(lower_bound, upper_bound) {}
    explicit randomStreamUniformInt(int lower_bound, int upper_bound, double seed)
    : mt(seed), uniform_dist(lower_bound, upper_bound) {}

    int operator() () { return uniform_dist(mt); }
private:
    std::mt19937_64                     mt;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<>     uniform_dist;
};

static randomStreamUniformInt rng(-MAXRANGE, MAXRANGE); 

std::vector<float> generate random(const std::size_t numElements) {
    std::vector<float> res(numElements);
    std::generate(res.begin(), res.end(), rng);
    return res;
}

std::vector<float> generate_orthogonal(const std::vector<float>& a) {
    // get some random data
    std::vector<float> b = generate_random(a.size());

    // find the last non zero entry in a
    // We have to turn the reverse iterator into an iterator via std::prev(rit.base())
    auto IsZero = [] (const float f) -> bool { return f == float(0.0);};
    auto end = std::prev(std::find_if_not(a.crbegin(), a.crend(), IsZero).base());

    // determine the dot product up to end
    float dot_product = std::inner_product(a.cbegin(), end, b.cbegin(), float(0.0));

    // set the value of b so that the inner product is zero
    b[std::distance(a.cbegin(), end)] = - dot_product / (*end);

    return b;
}

int main() {
    std::size_t dimension = 20;

    std::vector<float> a = generate_random(dimension);
    std::vector<float> b = generate_orthogonal(a);
}
```

Comment: Oops, didn't notice you already posted an answer because my Internet connection sucks.  Sorry for the duplicate information!

Comment: BTW, it appears that your `generate_random` function will generate the same numbers every time.  Should `rng` be static?

Comment: Argh yes, Normally it would be passed around sorry

Comment: maybe mention that builtins like "inner_product" are likely to use SSE2/optimized code, so one more reason not to roll your own.

Comment: Also, `float(0.0)` is just `0.0f`.

Comment: A very minor nitpick, I try to keep people brand new to C++ away from reverse iterators because of how unintuitive their behaviour can be.

Comment: @L.F. that is correct. However, as it turns out the algorithm right now would also work for other types if one would templatize the function. using 0.0f would not